# How do i make my Bot look for the possible Permissions which are given in an list

Tags: node.js, discord.js

i have quite a problem. I have coded a help command for my bot which lists all available sommands which are stored. Now that i have some Categories of Commands i wanna make sure only people with specific permissions get to see the specific commands. I made a try but it doesn't work well, even though their role has the specific permission it doesn't show the categorys but does show the ones which are stated in the `else{}` line. Here is the code:

```
const permissionlist = [
          "BAN_MEMBERS",
          "KICK_MEMBERS",
          "VIEW_AUDIT_LOG",
          "MANAGE_CHANNELS",
          "MANAGE_NICKNAMES",
          "MANAGE_MESSAGES",
          "MUTE_MEMBERS"
        ]

if(message.member.hasPermission(permissionlist)){
            fs.readdirSync("./commands/").forEach((dir) => {
              const commands = fs.readdirSync(`./commands/${dir}/`).filter((file) =>
                file.endsWith(".js")
              );
      
              const cmds = commands.map((command) => {
                let file = require(`../../commands/${dir}/${command}`);
      
                if (!file.name) return //"No command name.";
      
                let name = file.name.replace(".js", "");
      
                return `\`${name}\``;
              });
      
              let FileData = new Object();
      
              FileData = {
                name: dir.toUpperCase(),
                value: cmds.length === 0 ? "In progress." : cmds.join(" "),
              };

              const InvalidDirs = [
                  'minecraft-server',
                  'owner-only',
                  'customizable'
              ]

              if (InvalidDirs.includes(dir)) return              

              categories.push(FileData)
            });
          }
```

Notice: I have all other code already prepared for the messages and the message works fine. I only need help how to make it that if a user has a specific permission out of that list that the message shows up with every other category except the ones which are stated in the `InvalidDirs` list.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if the GuildMember's permissions flags are included in your array:

```js
const permissionlist = [
          "BAN_MEMBERS",
          "KICK_MEMBERS",
          "VIEW_AUDIT_LOG",
          "MANAGE_CHANNELS",
          "MANAGE_NICKNAMES",
          "MANAGE_MESSAGES",
          "MUTE_MEMBERS"
        ];

if(permissionList.some(permission => message.member.permissions.FLAGS.includes(permission))){
  ...
}
```

References:
https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Permissions?scrollTo=s-FLAGS
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some